# Status bar hidden by default in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I have a flutter app built on version Flutter 3.10.5.

**Problem**

Strangely, the status bar is invisible. When I hot restart a screen, the app bar shows up, and is visible on all screens, until I navigate to any screen.

Here's how my material app looks:

```
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'title',
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              // statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
              statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
              statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
            ),
          ),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        initialRoute: Routes.splash,
        onGenerateRoute: widget.appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
      ),
```

**EDIT**

My guess is that the app is going in full screen mode by default. How do I restrict this?

Comment: it keeps happening on physical devices? have you tried to use your own mobile device to debug this? Maybe is just a Simulator bug...

Comment: @MarceloArthur Unfortunately I've observed the same issue on Android and iPhones as well :(

Comment: try to record the behavior on android simulator and share here with us as a GIF